# Recursion and html render

Tags: javascript, html, loops, recursion, frontend

Need your help. I try to render an HTML list using recursion but get stuck. Please give a hint on how to resolve this. I`m new in js, sorry.
Need to get nested lists. If you have a sublist in your object you have to create a sublist (using ul tag and post here all lines using li tags)

```
    function recursion(value) {
          if (Array.isArray(value)) {
            let subStr = '';
            subStr += '<ul>' + value.map(
              item => (`<li id=${item.id}>${item.subList ? recursion(item.subList) : item.text}</li>`)) + '</ul>'
            console.log(subStr)
            return subStr.split(',').join('')
          } else {
            let str = '';
            for (let subValue of Object.values(value)) {
              str += recursion(subValue)
            }
            body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', str);
          }
        }
        
        console.log(recursion(initState))
```

```
     const initState = {
          elements: [
            {id: 0, text: 'yo'},
            {id: 1, text: 'ku'},
            {
              id: 2, text: 'mu', subList: {
                elements: [{id: 2 - 1, text: 'sublist-mu-1'}, {id: 2 - 2, text: 'sublist-mu-2'}]
              }
            },
            {
              id: 3, text: 'zu', subList: {
                elements: [{
                  id: 3 - 1, text: 'sublist-zu', subList: {
                    elements: [{id: 3 - 1 - 1, text: 'subList-zu-zu-1'}, {id: 3 - 1 - 2, text: 'subList-zu-zu-2'}]
                  }
                }]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

Comment: You really need to show what sort of output you're trying to create.

Comment: [ 
 ['0', 'yo'],
 ['1','ku'], 
 ['2', 'mu', [['2-1', 'sublist-mu-1'],['2-2', 'sublist-mu-2']],
 ['3', 'zu', ['3-1', 'sublist-zu', [['3-1-1', subList-zu-zu-1], ['3-1-2', 'subList-zu-zu-2']]]] 
]

Comment: `id: 3 - 1` this is id: 2. You need to put quotation marks around it to make it a string. `id: "3 - 1"`

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this is not what you're looking for, but it matches the output mentioned in a comment:

```js
const convert = (es) => es .map (({id, text, subList}) => [
  String(id),
  text,
  ...(subList ?.elements ?.length ? [convert (subList .elements)] : [])
])
  
const elements = [{id: 0, text: 'yo'}, {id: 1, text: 'ku'}, {id: 2, text: 'mu', subList: {elements: [{id: 2 - 1, text: 'sublist-mu-1'}, {id: 2 - 2, text: 'sublist-mu-2'}]}}, {id: 3, text: 'zu', subList: {elements: [{id: 3 - 1, text: 'sublist-zu', subList: {elements: [{id: 3 - 1 - 1, text: 'subList-zu-zu-1'}, {id: 3 - 1 - 2, text: 'subList-zu-zu-2'}]}}]}}]
 
console .log (convert (elements))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This simple function generates the String id, the text, and, if you have a subList with elements, a child array.

If you are actually looking to generate HTML, as the tag suggests and as does your own attempt, then please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73491991/edit) your post to include the output you're trying to generate.